# How do I display full stack trace in Nodeunit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodeunit

How do I display a full stack trace when nodeunit catches errors? For example, my test is throwing:

```
✔ event delete - basic
✔ delete - errors
Fatal error: undefined is not a function
```

How do I get nodeunit to tell me where `undefined` is being called as a function?

Comment: Could you please include some of your test code? The docs mention nothing about nodeunit hiding stack traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with grunt-contrib-nodeunit: it modifies the raw nodeunit messages into something less useful. I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-nodeunit/issues/32).

In short, the code that I have produced output like this with grunt-contrib-nodeunit:

```
user@desktop:~/bug_test$ grunt
Running "nodeunit:all" (nodeunit) task

test.js
Fatal error: undefined is not a function
```

Plain nodeunit gives a more helpful error message:

```
user@desktop:~/bug_test$ nodeunit test.js 

test.js

FAILURES: Undone tests (or their setups/teardowns): 
- testSomethingElse

To fix this, make sure all tests call test.done()
```

And, as shown in the issue,when there is a stack to share grunt-contrib-nodeunit will, on occasion, hide it.

Note that the choice of reporter (grunt, default, or minimal) did not make a difference.

The solution is to always run your tests with nodeunit directly whenever you get a less than helpful error message. There may be new information.